# which community would be able to help me find adequate networking devices for securing home use and plain networking

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I need to buy the simplest set of networking devices that provide adequate security

which community would be able to give insight into which devices i should buy or which concepts need to be available on the network to accomplish adequate security

Comment: Your list of requirements is a little vague.  Surely any Netgear box will do?

Comment: A better question would be something like  "What should I look for in a Wireless Access Point?"  The answer to which is "It's complicated.  Look for modern boxes, and [get them properly configured.](https://www.cybintsolutions.com/this-is-what-you-need-to-know-about-wireless-network-security/)."

Comment: @RobertHarvey I tried to not go into details because I was trying to keep my question relevant without rambling (i've never had good luck with formatting questions over here). simply put, i'm afraid someone got my netgear box firmware somehow. i think this is the case because im locked out of the box regardless of how many factory resets i run, and it wont even accept it's own serial code anymore for password resets.

Comment: @RobertHarvey that being said, i believe an attacker that has my current firmware can probably get another firmware given they are already so committed. a suggestion to a different, probably-safer, box is what i'm looking for. I would also like any other pieces of information like safer wifi, but I know just how complicated that gets, so i'm trying not to ramble here

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In theory such questions can go [Hardware Recommendations](https://hardwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) but not the one you ask here, in this exact form.

In general recommendation questions (also known as shopping questions) are off-topic across the Stack Exchange network. More often then not these questions attract spam or low quality contributions that no-one is helped with now, let alone future visitors.

For that reason the two sites that do take recommendation question have invested in a strict quality model for questions, so that the answers have value for you and others.

From the help center of Hardware Recommendations:

> Your question on Hardware Recommendations should:
>
> Clearly define requirements - Objectively define what the hardware
>   must do and must not do. e.g., "must be less than $100" is good; "must
>   be cheap" is bad). Include optional requirements, if any.
>
> Show previous research - Tell us what products you are aware of that
>   do not meet your needs. Otherwise, you may get those products as
>   recommendations, wasting your time and ours.
>
> Provide relevant details in the question - Links are useful for
>   supporting your information but visiting them should not be required
>   to answer effectively, in case they stop working.
>
> Include a good title - Briefly summarize your goal in a few words and
>   mention only one or two of the most important requirements (e.g.,
>   "25-inch monitor under $150"). See "How do I write a good title" for
>   more tips.
>
> Make use of tags - Tags help sort questions. Use them to categorize
>   your question and narrow the scope of your request. Avoid using
>   too-broad tags on their own.
>
> Have a narrow scope - Only ask for one piece of hardware at a time and
>   focus on what you need from that item. If you need multiple items, ask
>   more than one question.

So your first task is now to write a question that adhere to the above guideline and only  after achieving that, consider posting.